# fourth child set at first position with jquery

Tags: jquery, append

Hi my html structure like below

```
<ul>
  <li class="inner_m">first</li>
  <li class="inner_m">second</li>
  <li class="inner_m">third</li>
  <li class="inner_m">fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Now how will i set this structure by jQuery like below

```
<ul>
  <li class="inner_m">fourth</li>
  <li class="inner_m">first</li>
  <li class="inner_m">second</li>
  <li class="inner_m">third</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Is it always the fourth or did you mean the last sibling?

Comment: it can be any child like some time come 2nd child above some time 3rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift all siblings down and wrap the last one up:

```
$('li:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/mojakide/1/)

You can use `$('li:nth-child(4)')` as well here, but `:last-child` happens to be the same thing in your case.

The reason I'm using `.each()` here is because doing will make it work consistently if you have multiple `<ul>` blocks.

Or using plain JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li:last-child'), function(node) {
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(node, node.parentNode.firstChild);
});
```

Comment: @Riturajratan Yeah, so you can use `$('li:eq(whatever)')` to choose the sibling you need to move to first place instead of `'li:last-child'` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.eq(3)` to select fourth element and then use `.prepend()` to add at first position.try this:

```
$("ul").prepend($(".inner_m:eq( 3 )"));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaLPZ/)**

Answer (score 1):

> Use ***prepend()*** in  jquery

```
$("ul li:eq(3)").remove();
$("ul").prepend("<li class='inner_m'>fourth</li>");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49ZYF/)

or

```
$('li:last-child').prependTo('ul');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select any row

https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

or for selecting last you can use .last()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before()` method for that.

```
$('li:eq(0)').before($('li:eq(3)'));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/35/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $this= $('.inner_m:eq(3)');
   $this.insertBefore($this.siblings(':eq(0)'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/79/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $li_fo = $('li').eq(3);
    $li_fo.prependTo('ul');
});
```

Comment: Could you add a description? Your answer is currently incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend method for this.here is the solution for your problem.

```
$('li:last-child').each(function() {
$(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});

http://jsfiddle.net/S96qP/
```